# Creating data recovery page - no syntax errors but nothing is working as expected - php

Tags: php

I am following a tutorial that show how to rest an username along with a password.  However, I like to challenge myself in order to learn the logic behind what is being taught by changing the concept to something like resting the email and password instead (since the requirement in the code will be different compared to what is being covered in the tutorials).  It may sound straight forward and I know it's for experienced and savvy programmers, however I'm learning the trade of programming slowly but surely. I am trying to be better with  help from you guys as I have gotten a little further without any errors, however the output I should get from the code thus far is not happening.  I have included all the code I have been following on the tutorial and I am not sure how to fix it.  If the code had worked as expected, then I should either get an "OK" message or "Sorry" error.  Thank you all for your help.  I should have mentioned that I get a blank page!

```
 <br /> <br /><p3>Retrieve Email</p3> <br /> <br />

 <?php
    function user_data($user_id){
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

        $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if($func_num_args > 1){
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args). '`';
    $data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM  `users` WHERE `user_id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."'"));
    return $data;
    }

   }

?>

<?php
  $mode_allowed = array('email', 'passwd');
  if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed) === true){
     if(isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name']) === true && empty($_POST['first_name']) === false && empty($_POST['last_name']) === false){
        if((($_POST['first_name'] === $user_data['first_name']) && ($_POST['last_name'] === $user_data['last_name'])) && $user_data['user_id'] === true){
            $message[] = '<p class="postad_msg">ok</p>';
         }
         else{
             $errors[] = '<p class="postad_msg">Sorry, we could not find your records!</p>';
          }
                        }
      ?>

     <form method="post" action="retrieve">
         <fieldset>              
           <label for="first_name">First Name * : </label>
           <input placeholder="Your first name" type="text" name="first_name" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($first_name); ?>" /><br /><br />
           <label for="last_name">Last Name * : </label>
           <input placeholder="Your last name" type="text" name="last_name" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($last_name); ?>" /><br /><br />

       </fieldset>

       <fieldset class="center1">
           <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Retrieve Email " />
       </fieldset>                      

       <?php echo output_errors($errors); ?>
       <?php echo output_message($message);?>
     </form>
    <?php
     }
     else
 {
      //Redirect user to index for example                      
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: I have tried to retrace where I might be having a problem and it seems after the first if(isset($_GET... I am able to echo something to the page.  This would indicated my problem is with the second if(isset($_POST..... because when I attempt to get an output after that if statement I get a blank page.  Hopefully this may shed some light but I am definitely gonna keep on going till I figure it out or someone helps direct me in the right approach.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tried to get a way from what I was following the tutorial and decided to take a shot at it using what I have learned from previous tutorials and create a different approach. I have test this and it works 100%.  Please for those who are PHP savvy any feedback/comment on the code is greatly appreciated. Also I decided not retrieve email info instead this code shows  Resetting password.  However, I believe with this code retrieve email info should be straight forward as well. Thank you!  Here is the code

----fucntions----

```
 function retrieve($email){
 $email     = sanitize($email);

 $user_data = user_data(user_id_from_email($email), 'user_id', 'first_name');
 if ($mode = 'passwd'){

 $generated_passwd = substr(sha1(rand(999, 999999)), 0, 8);
 change_passwd($user_data['user_id'], $generated_passwd);
 email($email, 'Account Password Recovery', "Hello " . $user_data['first_name'] . ",\n\n Your new password is:" . $generated_passwd . " \n\nPlease change your password next time you login \n\n- Admin Team.");
    }
}

  function user_data($user_id){
  $data = array();
  $user_id = (int)$user_id;

  $func_num_args = func_num_args();
  $func_get_args = func_get_args();

  if($func_num_args > 1){
  unset($func_get_args[0]);

  $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args). '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM  `users` WHERE `user_id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."'"));
        return $data;
    }
}

  function email_exists($email){
  $email = sanitize($email);
  return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

  function user_id_from_email($email){
  $email = sanitize($email);
  return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0, 'user_id');
}
```

-----Retrieve PHP file ----

```
  require_once ("core/init.php"); 
  redirect_registered(); 

        if(empty($_POST) === false)
        {
            $required_fields = array('user_id', 'email');
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true)
                {
                    $errors[] = '<p class="postad_msg">Fields marked with * are required</p>';
                    break 1;
                }
            }
            if(isset($_POST['email']) === true && !empty($_POST['email']))
            {     
                if(email_exists($_POST['email']) === true)
                {
                    output_message($message);
                }
                else
                {
                    $errors[] = '<p class="postad_msg">Sorry, your email is not in the database.  Please try another email!</p>';
                }
             }  
        }
    ?>
  <?php require ("includes/overall/header.php");?>

  <div id="mainInfo">

  <br /> <br /><p3>Reset Password</p3> <br /> <br />
            <?php   
               if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success']))
              {
                 $message[] = '<p class="postad_msg"> Your Password has been reset.  Please check your email.</p>'; 
              }
                    if(!empty($_POST) && empty($errors) === true)
                    {      
                        retrieve($_POST['email']);
                        header('Location: retrieve?success');
                        exit();                                                 
                    }
                    else if(empty($errors) === false)
                    {
                        output_errors($errors); 
                    }
              ?>

                <form method="post" action="retrieve">
                    <fieldset>              

                        <label for="email">Email* : </label>
                        <input placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" /><br /><br />
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset class="center1">
                        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset Password" />
                    </fieldset>
                        <?php echo output_errors($errors); ?>
                        <?php echo output_message($message);?>                             
                </form>
    </div>
```

A million thanks to the original tutor on youtube (Alex Garrett) and all of you who make learning PHP fun and challenging.  I hope this can be of help.

Cheers!